# Firebase function deployment- Function can't be found in local source code error

Tags: javascript, firebase-tools

I'm trying to deploy my Firebase project's functions but I'm getting a message telling me that my function can't be found in my local source code but it's there, so now I'm stuck.

my IDE and terminal:

[image]

I did some research but all I'm getting is that I should make sure that my function is in my local source code which it is. I've also tried initializing my project again to see if I could start fresh but it did not work.